# Vuex state not updating from local storage

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm having some problems getting the Vuex state to update from local storage when visiting a route directly from the address bar in an incognito window.

When visiting the route `/shop/:key?` directly (for example clicking a link from an email) the mounted action `getDetail` is executed and local storage is updated but the state is not reevaluated - it still says undefined as if the key doesn't exist.

Is there a way to get the state to be reevaluate or does it have to be updated in the `setDetail` mutation?

```
const state = {
    key: localStorage.getItem('key'),
    details: null
}

const actions = {
    async getDetail({ commit }, key) {
        const details = await Service.detail(key)
        commit('setDetail', details)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setDetail(state, details) {
        state.details = details
    }
}

const Service = {
    detail: async function(key) {
        const url = `/store/${key}/`
        const response = await ApiService.get(url)
        localStorage.setItem('key', key)
        return response.data
    }
}
```

Comment: This could [help:](https://www.mikestreety.co.uk/blog/vue-js-using-localstorage-with-the-vuex-store), you need to call mutation when component is created. Let me know if you need then I can create a demo for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state will be re-evaluated if a mutation (or action) occurs. You could change the state directly but this is advised against as it breaks reactivity.

`LocalStorage` is not reactive and as such you need to update the state using a `mutation` or an `action`.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` might be returning a `string` instead of a `boolean` which if not properly handled could lead to vuex not updating state accordingly.